# No retraction theorem for a cube

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, algebraic-topology

I recently came across the following version of the no retraction theorem which asserts the non-existence of a continuous function $f$ mapping the unit ball $B\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to its boundary $S$ such that $f(x) = x$ for all $x\in S.$

This can be proved using the fixed point theorem, however, I was wondering if it is possible to prove this result for a cube in $\mathbb{R}^3.$ More, formally let $\mathbb{D} = [-1,1]^3$ and let $\partial \mathbb{D}$ denote the boundary of $\mathbb{D}.$ Then does there exist a continuous map $f:\mathbb{D} \to \partial\mathbb{D}$ such that $f(x) = x,\forall x\in \partial \mathbb{D}$?

Comment: You know that there is a relative homeomorphism $(I^n,\partial I^n)\cong (D^n,S^{n-1})$?

Comment: Choose a homeomorphism $h\colon B \cong \mathbb{D}$. In particular, $h(\partial B) = \partial \mathbb{D}$. If $f$ is a retraction from $\mathbb{D}$ to $\partial\mathbb{D}$ then $h^{-1}fh$ is a retraction from $B$ to $\partial B$.

Comment: @Tyrone I did not know that. Could you please give a reference for this statement?

Comment: Write $\widetilde I =[-1,1]$. Define $\theta:\widetilde I^n\rightarrow D^n$ by $\theta(t)=\frac{\max|t_i|}{\|t\|}(t_1,\dots,t_n)$ for $t=(t_1,\dots,t_n)\neq 0$ and by $\theta(0)=0$. This is one direction of the homeomorphism.